# Cant import FreeCAD to Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cad, freecad

Im having a little problem when I try to import from a Python file, which is placed in an another folder, to FreeCAD. 
Python file location : `c:/users/workspace/main.py`
FreeCAD : `c:/program files (x86)/FreeCAD0.13/bin`

when I'm trying to import with the command  `from FreeCAD import *` ( I'm appending FreeCAD's path to `sys  sys.path.append (" path-To-FreeCADs-BinFolder " )` 
I get an error  :

```
FreeCAD 0.13, Libs: 0.13R1828
Initialization of FreeCAD failed:
While initializing FreeCAD the  following exception occurred:
''module' object has no attribute 'PrintError''
Please contact the application's support team for more information. "
```

But when i create a Python file in FreeCAD 's folder it works. I mean with import FreeCAD like I wrote above.

ps : My Python Version is 2.7.5 and FreeCAD is : 0.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and surfing around I found that Win version doesn't support Python2.7, so you have to install Python 2.6, open a shell and do the same
import sys
sys.path.append('C://Program Files//FreeCAD0.13/bin')
import FreeCAD

Then it should work

Comment: Better still `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/freecad-python3/lib`